# How to change value of variable like redux but with react-hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Maybe my question doesn't match. How to change the value of a variable using another component? I want to use react-hooks to change value like redux.
For example, I have variable `const [message, setMessage] = useState('');` ,that location in `SearchScreen.js`file. And I want to change value of this variable in `Test.js` file.

```
//SearchScreen file
import 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import React,{ useState } from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';
const SearchScreen = ({navigation}) =>{
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
    return(
            <View>
                <Text>{message}</Text>
                <Button
                    title='enter to next bar'
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Test')}
                />
            </View>
        );
};

export default SearchScreen;
```

and another file

```
//Test file
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
const Test = () =>{
    return(
        <View>
            <Text>
            </Text>
        </View>
    );
};

export default Test;
```

Can I write immediately `setMessage('Testing')` in `Test.js` file

Comment: Where are you using the `Test` component?

Comment: @IanVasco component it's meaning another screen. But there Test is not component. When I pressed to button. My screen go to Test component.

Comment: Please show the entire usage of `Test` in order to help you. There are plenty of options

Comment: This is all of entire of Test file. I want to change value of ```message``` variable in ```Test.js``` file. If you mean how is your screen go to Test screen. There is no mistake in root file as ```App.js```.

Comment: @IanVasco Can I use react-hooks like a redux: to change value as global?

Comment: you need to use context!!! or why you are not using redux !

Comment: @adel As I heard, we can use react-hooks instead of redux.

Comment: check this link if you want to use react-hooks for state management: https://medium.com/simply/state-management-with-react-hooks-and-context-api-at-10-lines-of-code-baf6be8302c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send CallBack for setMessage value message through navigation

```
import React,{ useState } from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';
const SearchScreen = ({navigation}) =>{
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
    return(
            <View>
                <Text>{message}</Text>
                <Button
                    title='enter to next bar'
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Test',{setMessage})}
                />
            </View>
        );
};

export default SearchScreen;
```

after that get this callback from navigation props like in you test route

Test file

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
const Test = (props) =>{
const {navigation} = props;
const setMessage = navigation.state.params.setMessage;
    return(
        <View>
            <Text>
            </Text>
        </View>
    );
};

export default Test;
```

for documentation check [send value to other screen](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html)

Comment: Is it right way to use useState to global variable?

Comment: I mean change value like as redux, but via react-hooks

Comment: if you are using it too much then its not recommended to use like this. Instead use react context api or redux.

Comment: Can I use react-hooks like redux. To change value of variable. Without putting the props?